# Spring Documentation: what does it mean by "can only be used in a Java 5 environment"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I was reading a doc about spring 3.1 [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#threadPoolTaskExecutor)

It says "`This implementation can only be used in a Java 5 environment`", but in the project, JDK is already set as 7.

And I have this bean working normally:

```
    <bean id="taskExecutor"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor"
        scope="prototype">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="2" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="keepAliveSeconds" value="10" />
        <property name="queueCapacity" value="999999999" />
    </bean>
```

So what does it mean in the doc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` implementation requires classes  from `java.util.concurrent` package to work. This package first appeared in Java 1.5.

> So what does it mean in the doc?

It means you can't use `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` on Java 1.4. Strictly speaking, there are some ways to backport `java.util.concurrent` to older Java versions, but Spring documentation claims these backports to be uncompartible with `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` implementation.

All Java version since 1.5 (including 1.7 you're using) are fine, so you have nothing to worry about here.

Comment: Ok so it means **SINCE** certain version, just a little bit confused. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best to look at the classes being referenced.
That is what it is based on:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

and if you look Java 7
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

they are identical and notice
Since:
1.5

I'd say the documentation refers to it to be on safe side binding language compliance to Java 5 for spring 3.1.